# Magento my processing order count

Tags: magento, count

How can I get count of customer's processing order status ??

Like Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount().

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **only the number** of orders in a processing state…

```
$processingOrdersCount = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
    ->getSize()
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question that loads the order collection with the 'status' field you are after:

[Get order ids with status = 'Complete' in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309289/get-order-ids-with-status-complete-in-magento)